# Regarding Mutexes and Semaphors

Tags: multithreading

Suppose there are 4 Threads (T1 to T4) that need to run concurrently and 3 structs (Struct1 to Struct3) as resources

T1 to T2 share struct1 (by T1 writing to struct1 and T2 reading from it)

T2 to T3 share struct2 (by T2 writing to struct2 and T3 reading from it)

T3 to T4 share struct3 (by T3 writing to struct3 and T4 reading from it)

Because of this statement from § 41.2.4 of The C++ Programming Language (4th edition) by Bjarne Stroustrup :

> "Two threads have a data race if both can access a memory location
>   simultaneously and at least one of their accesses is a write. Note
>   that defining “simultaneously” precisely is not trivial. If two
>   threads have a data race, no language guarantees hold: the behavior is
>   undefined."

It becomes clear there is a need for syncrhonization.

1 - Which of these primitives are suitable to this application , just mutices or Semaphores ?

2- If mutex is the choice, we would need 3 mutices, one mutex for each structure , right ?

3- Would the fact of using a mutex at a given non-atomic operation, block CPU time of other threads ?

Comment: You would want to check the id of the thread each time before reads and writes.

Comment: What are you doing with the data? Are you wanting to block until some thread updates the data (like producer/consumer) or are you just accessing them concurrently?

Comment: Any perceived resemblance to any homework/assignment question is purely coincidental.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers  well just based on the description above, it looks like there are three Producer/consumer interactions. All my question was, based on the described scenario, what is the best synchronization method that would prevent both race and deadlock conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Your usecase is kind of abstract so batter solutions might be available. But based just on the information you provided:

1) Use mutex. I do not see how semaphores could help except to be used as mutex. A semaphore could be usefull when you share more resources, but in your case it is only one at a time.

If all four threads would access the first free struct or if your struct would be an queue, a semaphore could help.

2) Right, one mutex per structure.

3) Yes, it could, this is the idea, you do not want for T1 to write when T2 is reading struct1 and viceversa. Worstcase could be T1 blocks T2 that has already blocked T3 that has blocked T4.

Comment: I'd add that while mutexes will certainly solve any race conditions, they can't be used if there's any ordering required for data access.  For example, if thread T2 isn't supposed to read from struct1 until thread T1 has written to it, and if thread T1 isn't supposed to write to struct1 again until T2 has read it, a mutex won't be sufficient.  With just a mutex, T2 could read the same value that T1 wrote more than once, or it could instances of T1 writing.

Comment: @Dragos Pop  good point regarding the worst case scenario. So in that case, what happens, does that lead to some kind of CPU issues...What would happen in the scenario you described

Comment: @SamGomari In this case nothing very bad, your application will not fully use a multicore CPU. But it would not keep them busy, so other applications can use them, or your computer will use less energy, important for laptops. But if you would have a struct4 shared by T4 and T1, than a deadlock could appear [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)

Comment: @DragosPop   actually it's great you mentioned this, because the program i'm trying to fix has an inherent loop "control system". Thus far i'm using mutexes....but it seems like this coffman's deadlock is bound to happen in accordance with the definition in the link u provided. Would condition variables or semaphores fix the problem ?

Comment: I cannot give you an answer since I don't know the implementation and the solutions depend on this. It does not matter what low level synchronization primitive you are using, it can cause deadlock if you do not take care. This can be solved in higher level, for example: only lock a mutex during read and write of a shared variable, this way you would know that if T1 keeps T2 waiting it does not wait itself for T4.

Answer (score 0):

1 - 3 semaphore for each queue, see [Producer–consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)).

2- 1 of the semaphores could be a mutex, binary semaphores are much like mutex.

3- if you have to wait for a semaphore or mutex you will be placed in the no ready queue of the OS, waiting for the release. And so doesn't use any CPU (except for the 1000's of cycles it cost for the context switch).